# How to use SLURM to make hostefile for mpirun

Tags: bash, mpi, openmp, hpc, slurm

I have access to a HPC with 40 cores on each node. I have a batch file to run a total of 35 codes which are in separate folders. my each code is an open mp code which requires 4 cores each. so how do I allocate 4 nodes such that each code gets 4 core. please tell me how to use `$SLURM_JOB_NODELIST` this env as I know gives the list of nodes assigned in the queue..Basically my idea is to make nodefile in each folder and then use that in mpirun.

is there is any other way that slurm automatically allocates the said resources. because without nodefile all my codes go into a single node while all other nodes remain empty.

````
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --error=job.err 
#SBATCH --output=job.out 
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00 
#SBATCH --job-name=a20 
#SBATCH --partition=cpu 
#SBATCH --nodes=4 
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=10 
```
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4 

let tasks_per_job=1 
let threads_per_task=4 
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$threads_per_task 
module load intel/2018.0.1.163 

cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR 
cd a20 

k=1

for j in */* 
do 
  cd $j
  sed -n $k,$k'p' < $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST >nodefile$k 
  mpirun -np $tasks_per_job --hostfile nodefile$k ./chk >& job$k.out & 

  sleep 2 

  let k=$k+1 
  cd ../.. 
done

wait
````

Comment: Crossposting: https://superuser.com/q/1652357/340330

Comment: It seems you are trying to run a bunch of single node 4 OpenMP threads jobs. In this case, your best option is a SLURM job array. If you are constrained to a single and large allocation, consider using flux https://github.com/flux-framework/flux-core (basically, run your own resource scheduler all in user-space within a SLURM allocation)

Answer (score 1):

so I have found the solution
you can use the following `scontrol show hostname $SLURM_NODELIST`  (the two back ticks are important)
to get an expanded list of nodes and then convert it to an array and then use the following logic to assign codes to specific nodes.

#!/bin/bash

```
#SBATCH --time=48:00:00
```

#SBATCH --job-name=a80

```
#SBATCH --partition=cpu
```

#SBATCH --nodes=5

```
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=7
```

#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=5

let tasks_per_job=1

```
let threads_per_task=5
```

let tasks_per_node=7

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$threads_per_task
```

module load intel/2018.0.1.163

cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR

list=`scontrol show hostname $SLURM_NODELIST`

```
n_arr=($list)
```

```
cd a80
```

k=1

```
v=0
```

for j in */*/

```
do
```

cd $j

```
ifort HI_final_mkl_openmp.f90 -mkl -qopenmp -xHOST -align array64byte -o chk
```

rm nodefile*

```
rm job*.out
```

echo "${n_arr[$v]}" >nodefile$k

```
mpirun  -np $tasks_per_job  -hostfile nodefile$k ./chk  >& job$k.out &
```

if [[ $k -eq $tasks_per_node ]]

```
then
```

let v=$v+1

```
k=0
```

fi

```
sleep 2
```

let k=$k+1

```
cd ../..
```

done

```
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by Libin inspired this one. This should be a more concise and generalized solution:

```
nodelist=$(scontrol show hostname $SLURM_NODELIST)
printf "%s\n" "${nodelist[@]}" > nodefile
```

You can then pass `nodefile` to your command. I would recommend adding `rm nodefile` at the end to clean up the space since it is a temporary file.